# Why is my form not populating the data using ngModelGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a below form, where i am using `ngModelGroup` to group the inputs.

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
    <fieldset ngModelGroup="user">
        <div>
            <label>Firstname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" [(ngModel)]="firstname">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Lastname:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" [(ngModel)]="lastname">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset ngModelGroup="address">
        <div>
            <label>Street:</label>
            <input type="text" name="street" [(ngModel)]="street">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Zip:</label>
            <input type="text" name="zip" [(ngModel)]="zip">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>City:</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="city">
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When i map my `[(ngModel)] = "user.firstname" or "user.lastname" or "user.address.street"` it works? If i do in the above way, i don't see a reason why i need `ngModelGroup` in total.

I am not sure how to properly use `ngModelGroup` for `nested objects.`

Below is the plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Y4bjFh6sjtvdzkUWciid?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngModelGroup` lets you shape the data received from the form by introducing "subproperties".

**With `ngModelGroup="user"`** in your template, here's what `form.value` will look like:

```json
{
  "user": {
    "firstname": "foo",
    "lastname": "bar"
  },
  // ...
}
```

**Without `ngModelGroup="user"`** in your template, `form.value` will be:

```json
{
  "firstname": "foo",
  "lastname": "bar",
  // ...
}
```

`ngModelGroup` can be useful to give the form data the same shape as your data models. But it has no impact on the properties that you bind `[(ngModel)]` to (these properties can be whatever you want).